# Which layout for user-data plus a change-log is the most efficient and less storage consuming?

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql

My users can update their information, which is saved in a defined number of columns in a table, such as: `user ( id INT, email VARCHAR, phone VARCHAR, address VARCHAR )`, for example.

I have seen other implementations, like the one for Wordpress, that stores this information for its users in a table called `usermeta` with a layout `( umeta_id INT, user_id INT, meta_key VARCHAR, meta_value VARCHAR )`.

In the change log that I want to implement, I am evaluating between using a solution like that or making (what I think that will be better), a layout like: `userLog ( id INT, date TIMESTAMP, email VARCHAR, phone VARCHAR, address VARCHAR )`.
So, I can have a history of all the information any user had at a given date. Rows would only record the changes, having NULL on unaltered columns.

**For the first question**: Is there any advantage to this kind of layout other than being able to create new information type by just inserting an appropriate `meta_key`?
I sometimes think that this layout can be not really appropriate if performance is a matter in my environment, since I would be using a `VARCHAR` for every single kind of data that I want to store.

**For the second question**: Can storage and select/insert efficiency really make a difference between the two solutions I am considering?
Which solution should be less (or more) space-consuming and/or less (or more) select/insert efficient than the other and why?

Comment: What database system are you using?

Comment: @sufleR MySQL and PostgreSQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some thoughts, if not necessarily an answer:

Clearly a change log is a must-have for you, so the original structure with a single row per user is not a solution for you.  So we're talking about the choice between:

1. A single row per version of each user's entire information-set; or
2. A single row per version of the each user's item of information

Solution 1 corresponds to your

```
userLog ( id INT, date TIMESTAMP, email VARCHAR, phone VARCHAR, address VARCHAR )
```

Solution 2 corresponds to the Wordpress one:

```
umeta_id INT, user_id INT, meta_key VARCHAR, meta_value VARCHAR
```

**Your question 1:** I can't see any advantage to Solution2 except that, if you subsequently decide you want to capture users' (for example) Website URL or (for example) favourite colour as well, you can do that by adding a meta_key.  But you could equally easily do this under Solution1, by simply doing an

```
ALTER TABLE userlog ADD COLUMN WebSiteURL(etc)
```

That's not hard to do.  Unless the DBAs in your shop are unusually Dobermann-like ( ;)  ).  Because you're holding a change-log, all existing users (at the time of the change) will now have a blank WebsiteURL column; but that's exactly what you want: you don't know their WebsiteURL, because the system didn't capture it before.  Sure, the new column will have to be NULLABLE - but that may be unavoidable anyway, even with the "initial" data, unless the method you're using to capture user info insists on email, phone and address as required columns.

To me, the disadvantages of the meta_key solution outweigh the advantages.  The disadvantages are:

- You have to develop a piece of pivot code to pivot user info for one user onto one
  row.  You must call this code in every place you want to get user info on one row.  In 
  contrast, Solution1 only requires

  SELECT userID,[all user info] FROM userLog INNER JOIN (SELECT userID,MAX(datechanged) AS LatestDAteChanged FROM userlog GROUP BY userID) a ON userlog.userid=a.userID AND userlog.DateChanged=a.LatestDAteChanged

  which is far more efficient than a pivot.  With an index on UserID,DateChanged, this'll 
  run like the wind.
- Unless you really want to hold meta_key values multiple times in the userinfo table (Email, Email, Email, Email, Email), you'd need an extra Meta_Key_Lookup table.

**Second question:**
For ultimate space-efficiency, yes, the meta_key Solution2 is the best.  Especially if you don't use VARCHAR metakeys, but metakey ID values, and have a separate meta_key lookup table (e.g. 1=Email, 2=Phone etc).  But I don't think this is a conclusive argument for the meta_key Solution2, given the virtually-zero price of storage, and the difficulties involved in this solution.

(A note/thought: IMHO your idea of holding NULL values in your solution1, where the value has not changed, is a wrong road.  The coding to try to get the most recent email, then phone, then address (separately) for each user, will be a nightmare: almost as hard to code/test - and for the server to run - as the pivot required by the other solution.  And the reduction in storage marginal.  Just hold the entire row every time one thing changes.  Unless you're just giving examples, and the real user info-set is 50 columns wide...)

IMHO the storage issue is not decisive.  So let's turn to SELECT/INSERT efficiency:

On this issue, I think Solution1 still wins.  On Inserts, SOlution1 wins: only one row is inserted, even if the user changes every field in their info.  On SELECTS, SOlution 1 wins again: you only need a view of the most recent info per user (code above), which is the kind of thing SQL is optimised for.  In contrast, Solution2 would require a pivot: something SQL is not good at.

Comment: Actually I will insert, or rather update, on a single row, per user. The change log that holds NULL values will be populated by triggers. I think that this is the best approach I can think of now. Similar to what you said in your last paragraph.

Comment: An advantage of a generic solution (meta_key) is that it would allow you to store the change log of multiple tables (with an additional table key or a column key unique for all tables).

Comment: Hey, @sebt, in case you are interested... I did a test with two tables holding a row per user. One holding the entire data set of each user and the second one having only the changed data and NULL for the rest of the cells. Inserted around three million of random changes for different users in both tables and compared their size in hard disk. Guess what, both were exactly the same... really curious, maybe Postgres already does some kind of optimization for this kind of cases. Well, there you go. :P

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @sebt about standard SQL solutions.

If you need flexible solution in PostgreSQL I will recommend hstore type for you ([postgresql 9.1 docs](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/hstore.html)).
This type can store many key => value  pairs in one column.
There are many possible ways to insert, search and index this column. Documentation is a good way to start looking.

Answer (score 0):

The best choice largely depends on what you want to do, thus what queries you would be running (as with many things).

I don't quite understand the WordPress one (I get the fact that you store individual fields as rows, but I don't know where it fits in), so I'll just list all the options:

1. Have user and history tables store individual fields per row
2. Have only history table store individual fields per row
3. Have only user table store individual fields per row
4. Have neither store individual fields per row
5. Have 1 combined table for both user and history
6. Have 1 combined table for both storing individual fields per row

(5) and (6) doesn't really seem like options in most cases, as I suspect you'd want to get the details for a user (or a bunch of users) more often than you would want to get the history (unless most of your queries is to get both at the same time).

(1) and (3) are not advised, unless many of the details are not filled in (thus you'd end up with very sparse tables in other cases).

(4) is for when users tend to change all their details at once, which probably doesn't happen often, I suspect people just change 1 or 2 fields at a time. So, (2) is probably a better option, especially if the user table has many fields (and people just change 1 or 2 fields at a time).

Generally, storing individual fields per row is for reduced storage space above performance (assuming there are some empty fields, otherwise storing individual fields per row is hands-down worse), you basically determine which is best by looking at your requirements and the expected data. Note we're talking mainly about selecting here, which is generally the slow operation, unless you have some weird stuff going on, or tons of inserts at once. For history, reduced storage is generally preferred above performance, so (2).

Adding fields is generally a bit of effort in anyway, so just saying 'UPDATE user ADD COLUMN col' is not really a big deal, it can even be automated. This would be another (small) reason to prefer (2) above (4).